# How to check if the Cosmos DB emulator in a Docker container is done booting?

Tags: docker, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-emulator

We use the Cosmos DB emulator in a Docker container. The container is started together with the test. Sometimes during the first test, there is a read timeout when connecting and the tests are aborted. Is there any check we can run before the tests to verify that the Cosmos DB has completed initialization? For example by querying a specific URL?

Answer (score 3):

Emulator readiness can be checked using HTTP GET request to the following url: /_explorer/emulator.pem

Comment: How this get the status of the emulator? It returns the certificate and not if the database is ready.

Comment: It doesn't return status 200 until db is ready